# Objective c parse, count objects in background

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I try to get the number of queries I found in background. So I use countobjects method to get the number, but system has warning about it "A long-running operation is being executed on the main thread."

```
PFQuery *query2=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Comments"];
[query2 whereKey:@"Name" equalTo:globalName];
NSInteger CommentPoint=query2.countObjects;
```

so i change to this method, but i can't get numbers of count print in my console.

```
 [query2 countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) 
{
   if (!error) {
        // The count request succeeded. Log the count
       NSLog(@"Sean has played %d games", count);
   } else {
       // The request failed
   }
}];
```

My another question is how can I assign "count" to an Global NSinteger?

I tried this

```
PFQuery *query=[PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"AllPost"];
[query whereKey:@"PostUser" equalTo:globalName];
NSLog(@"globalname %@",globalName);
[query countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error) {
        self.objectCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:count];
        // The count request succeeded. Log the count
        NSLog(@"Sean has played %d games", count);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
}];

NSLog(@"objectCount %@",self.objectCount);
```

this is what console print out

```
2015-07-02 19:17:16.721 ParseNews[12598:608067] globalname Sheng
2015-07-02 19:17:16.721 ParseNews[12598:608067] objectCount (null)
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are not getting the count in the log? Or you don't know how to convert an int to an NSInteger? (And you should edit your question to actually put the question in the question, not a comment.)

Comment: Thanks, picciano..I already  update my question..First, I want to NSLog to work...But I also want to assign "count" to an NSInteger that is outside of  [query2 countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(int count, NSError *error) 
{ }.

Comment: So then, what is printed on the console? Anything? Try logging the error.

Comment: I don't see anything print out in my console..

Comment: I would be curious what 'globalName' is when the query is called. Also, if NOTHING is being printed, then (!error) is false. It'll be vital to know what the error is!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution for the 'how to save' could be to create a global NSNumber property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *objectCount;
```

then, inside the block:

```
self.objectCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:count];
```

Comment: remove NSInteger ArticlePoint=query.countObjects*5;

Comment: countObjects && countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock both execute the same query so this is no doubt causing an issue.