# How to get thumbnail image from parse, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, parse-platform, nsdata

I want to get thumbnail image or blank image first while app is loading image data from parse database. After finish loading, the image view will display the image I load from parse.
So far, I have following codes

```
PFFile *thumbnail = object1[@"PostFiles"];
NSData *imageData = [thumbnail getData];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
```

I use PFtableviewcontroller. when I scroll down, my code will load image, the controller can't move smoothly.

Comment: are you getting nsdata from url right?

Comment: NO..I just call NSData *imageData = [thumbnail getData] to get data..If you get nsdata use URL, it will be much more slower..

Comment: You can get all images on viewDidLoad and add them in an array. Then populate table from that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are running a synchronous call for a task that could take a varying amount of time. Try getting the NSData using InBackgroundWithBlock:

```
             image = nil; //prevent images from being shown erroneously
             [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                    if (data && !error) {
                        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                    } else {
                        //maybe set a default image here if there is none?
                    }
                }];
```

Comment: good point. you can set "image = nil;" just before to avoid this

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel, Check my another question see if you can help..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31149163/objective-c-parse-count-objects-in-background

Comment: I will take a look. I have also updated the solution above for any future lookers!